# Direct Comparison Test. Can someone tell me if I'm right

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So we have a series:

$$a_n = \frac{n + 3^n}{n+2^n},\quad n=1,2,\cdots$$

and I compare it with $b_n=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$, geometric series, and since $\frac{3}{2} > 1$ then the series diverges and by comparison $\frac{n +3^n}{n+2^n}$ also diverges. Is my solution right?

Comment: There's no need for that...the terms of the series do not even go to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But you should add more details: the series converges because$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n+3^n}{n+2^n}}{\left(\frac32\right)^n}=1.$$Since this limit exists and it belongs to $(0,\infty)$ and since the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac32\right)^n$, then so does your series.

Comment: thank homie i love uuuu

Answer (score 1):

I think Limit Comparison test is better, as $(n+3^n)/(n+2^n)$ is not necessarily greater than $(3/2)^n$

Taking $\lim_{n\to\infty}((n+3^n)/(n+2^n))/(3/2)^n=1,$ so it diverges as well